# I want to add caption on the image like whatsapp in my react native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Right now I am able to click image from expo camera and able to view it and save it in my phone. I want to add caption on that Image in my App created by expo like we can do in Whatsapp. How can I do that?

Comment: There is a component ImageBackground in react native. Use that component.

Comment: I need to save that image with caption in my gallery too.